# TLS used in iOS11 and kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9800

Tags: ios, ssl, ios11

We have an application which connects to our web server over SSL.
Most of the time it works fine, but sometimes some of the requests sent by application (we use URLSession for loading requests) to the server fail (in the URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:) with the following error:

> Error Domain=SyncCPConnectionErrorDomain Code=12 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={ErrorMessageKey=Error Domain=**NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200**
>   "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server
>   cannot be made." UserInfo={**_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9800**,
>   NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server
>   anyway?

We started debugging the problem (using tcp dump) and saw the following:

Sometimes the application (in the OS level I guess, since we don't have control on this) offers in the SSL handshake TLS 1.0 both as the minimum and the maximum SSL version, and the handshake finishes successfully.

In other connections, the application offers TLS 1.0 as the minimum version and TLS 1.2 as the maximum version. Then, the handshake concludes successfully in version TLS 1.2.

We saw that sometimes the full handshake is performed in TLS 1.0, while the resumed handshake is performed in TLS 1.2.

Since the checksum algorithms are different between versions, the client probably gets confused, or at least disagrees with the server regarding checksum definitions. Then the client (application) closes the connection with "Illegal Params" fatal alert. We assume that at this point we get the -9800 SSL error on one of the app connections.

Our server is configured to prefer TLS 1.2, but it supports also old TLS versions (as 1.0).

At first we had configured in our application the **App Transport Security** (ATS) with: **NSAllowsArbitraryLoads = true**

We removed it and thought it will force the application to always use TLS 1.2, but it didn't help.
We know that Apple's states that in iOS11, application should work only with TLS 1.2, but we see that this is not the case here
Any ideas what can cause to such a phenomena? Or how we can resolve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How is your ATS settings configured for this app currently ?  Specifically what value do you use for `NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion` and `NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy` ?   Setting `NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion` to TLSv1.2 will force the iOS client to use TLS 1.2 connections only, not sure if that would really solve your problem though.  Setting `NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy` to NO should open up more possible cipher suites which are acceptable by iOS.

I believe there are still bugs in iOS 11 sdk TLS implementation which can cause intermittent TLS handshake failures which we may have no control over.  Your best bet for now is to retry these connection errors at least once or twice before failing completely when you encounter an SSL/TLS connection error and keep investigating the root cause as it may be an invalid SSL cert installed on one of your servers or load balancers.  Could also be invalid/missing cipher suites for the giving TLS configuration on the server side which iOS doesn't support.